# Validation in excel sheet, depending on dropdown column value, make two other columns value same and disable one of those columns

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, dropdown

I need to add a validation in an excel sheet. The criteria is-

There are 3 columns-

- Max Calls (Numeric value)
- Complicated Calls (Numeric value) Only
- Complicated calls (Dropdown with values Y, N)

Validations-

1. `Complicated Calls` should be `<=` `Max Calls`. This validation I have
   achieved. I am using this formulae- `=$A2>=$B2`, I am throwing error
   when this satisfies.
2. Along with the above validation, I need to check this as well When `Only Complicated calls` value is `Y`, then `Max Calls` value
   should be equal to `Complicated calls`.

For this I am using the below validation.

- `=IF($C2="Y", ($A2),($B2))`

Here it works like this, if I enter the value of `Max Calls` and then select the dropdown value to be `Y`, then if I enter a larger value in `Complicated calls`, then it throws the validation error, the `Complicated calls` value becomes blank, but the value is not copied as I haven't added that in the formulae. But, if I had already entered values in `Max Calls` and `Complicated calls` and then go on to change the dropdown value, then nothing happens.

I need to run the validation upon selecting the dropdown value. **(Is it possible at all?)**
I tried using this in cell `B2` `=IF($C2="Y", ($A2),($B2))` but I think I need to apply it in cell `C2` i.e dropdown cell.

[image]

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is possible.
You could do a combination of the following data validation criteria: in col A) custom- formula: `=IF(AND($C1="Y",$B1>0),$A1=$B1,$A1>=$B1)`, in col B) custom formula: `=IF($C1="Y",$B1=$A1,$B1<=$A1)`, and in col C) list: `Y,N`. And then work with conditional formatting to highlight (e.g. in red) when invalid selections have been made.

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to use VBA

Comment: I tried the above formulae in all the cells mentioned, but it did not work at all, I am always getting the validation error